# How trivial is this? (Reference Request)

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-geometry, article-writing

I am writing a paper and at some point I make use of the proposition
"Any compact, convex set, may be represented as the set of solutions to a (possibly infinite) set of linear inequalities."
Is this a well-known theorem or result so that I can cite some paper or do I need to prove this? Or may be this is trivial enough for the reader to prove for himself.

PS: the community of our readers are not assumed to be linear programming experts, they are physicists.

Comment: It's the simplest case possible: finite dimensional euclidean space. @BigbearZzz

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane

Comment: @K.Sadri Sorry there was a problem with my connection and my comment disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement holds for any closed convex sets in a Banach space, assuming that by "infinitely many linear inequalities" includes uncountably many such inequalities.

This follows from the well-known fact that a closed convex set $C$ can be written as
$$
C = \bigcap\{H\supset C: H \text{  is a closed half-space} \}
$$
and the fact that $C\subset H$ can be formulated as a linear inequality. The above representation is a corollary of the [Geometric Hahn-Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem). If you're looking for a reference I'd suggest Convex Analysis by Rockafellar or any functional analysis textbook should have this result.

Comment: I believe this is called something like "dual representation" of a convex set by people in the area.